# Pie chart in "File Properties" not working

Tags: file-properties

I have upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 (F Fossa), but have noticed that the pie chart in the "properties" dialog box showing the storage space of a hard disk or externally mounted drive does not work. It just shows as all grey. The figures next to it are showing correctly. Is this a bug in the upgrade, or coincidence? Anything I can do to remedy it?

Thanks